# How to drop orig_to using postfix virtual domains?

Tags: postfix, email

With the virtual domains, the final mailbox receiving the email gets the orig_to email address in its header. Is there a way to prevent this (i.e. address translation without keeping the orig_to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean `X-Original-To` header instead `orig_to` header. String `orig_to` only appears in maillog. To disable it set parameter `enable_original_recipient = no` in `main.cf`

From [`postconf(5)`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#enable_original_recipient):

> enable_original_recipient (default: yes)
>
> > Enable support for the X-Original-To message header. This header is needed for multi-recipient mailboxes.
> >
> > When this parameter is set to yes, the cleanup(8) daemon performs duplicate elimination on distinct pairs of (original recipient, rewritten recipient), and generates non-empty original recipient queue file records.
> >
> > When this parameter is set to no, the cleanup(8) daemon performs duplicate elimination on the rewritten recipient address only, and generates empty original recipient queue file records.
> >
> > This feature is available in Postfix 2.1 and later. With Postfix version 2.0, support for the X-Original-To message header is always turned on. Postfix versions before 2.0 have no support for the X-Original-To message header.