# How to keep orig_to with maildrop?

Tags: postfix, debian-jessie

I have configured a personal mail server with Postfix + Maildrop and Mysql for virtual domains, mailbox and aliases.

My problem is the lost of the `orig_to` field only when maildrop comes in action after spamassassin.
Here logs when I send an email from an email account hosted in my server (they seem good for me) :

> May 21 17:25:04 ns5000052 postfix/pipe[8050]: 7E85B80017: to=<user@ns5000052.ip-1-2-3.net>, orig_to=<user+4626_24@ns5000052.ip-1-2-3.net>, relay=maildrop, delay=0.54, delays=0.52/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via maildrop service)

Here logs when I send an email from a gmail account (there is no trace of `orig_to` with maildrop...) :

> May 21 18:08:52 ns5000052 postfix/pipe[20233]: 34F2780017: to=<user@ns5000052.ip-1-2-3.net>, orig_to=<user+4626_8@ns5000052.ip-1-2-3.net>, relay=spamassassin, delay=5.4, delays=0.25/0/0/5.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
>   ...
>   May 21 18:08:52 ns5000052 postfix/pipe[20254]: 973C980017: to=<user@ns5000052.ip-1-2-3.net>, relay=maildrop, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via maildrop service)

I saw this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/661615/how-to-drop-orig-to-using-postfix-virtual-domains), but for me it is the reverse. I put `enable_original_recipient = yes` in my `main.cf` then restarted postfix, but no change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more researches and tries, I found a solution when I discovered the avalaible arguments list in master.cf (cf [man pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html)).

In `master.cf`, I replace the line

> spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
>     user=spamuser argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}

with this line

> spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
>     user=spamuser argv=/usr/bin/spamc -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${original_recipient}